# PHP Smarty tpl, call the same php code for all page

Tags: php, web, master-pages, smarty3

So I want to use smarty similar to how asp.net does master pages, that is I want to crate a master.tpl file, that takes care of consistently rendering most of the page(headers, footers, backgrounds, etc), however I have a drop down menu that I want on every page, and it has some dynamic data, I would like not call or reproduce this function in every php script that uses the master.tpl file, I would like a way that when ever that tpl file is used the correct scripts are run in addition.

I'm looking to do this the correct way, so not using {php} or anything else that is deprecated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up writing a plugin (which was much simpler than I initially thought), and just returning a string, contain `<li>` items, I wonder if it would be possible to just call this function in a foreach loop, I could not get that to work last night.

Answer (score 0):

Render a seperate smarty template and add it in a config file

```
$smarty->assign('items',getmenuitems());


$menu = $smarty->fetch('mymenu.tpl');

$smarty->assign('dynamic_menu',$menu);
```

If you put code like this in a config file etc that's called on each page it should do what you want. Then {$dynamic_menu} can be put in your main template.

On another note I find that using a different delimiter for smarty removes the pain of using it worth scripts etc.

```
$smarty-> left_delimiter = '{[';
```

Comment: Hmm, do know much about this config file, probably something, I need to investigate further. I should not that the current hosting provider is a local business,and isn't the greatest support, so there might be a few things, I can do...

Comment: config files should not have any data calculation since it is a config file. Build it in more MVC way since You are using SMARTY for display layer.
And there are no need to fetch a tpl, pass to var and fetch the same data second time in more overall tpl. {include} would resolve that in maner that designer would not have a headacke.

Answer (score 0):

Just include it via smarty call. {include file="path" name_of_variable=$value_of_variable}. In php code just do additional code that data would be generated on every page.

Comment: I looked at the some earlier, but I thought that was just for including tpl files.

Comment: But You want to call a tpl file, just earlier supplied with values via code.

Comment: Not sure, I'm fully understanding, but what I want to do is really tightly couple a template, and its corresponding code behind page, so that whenever the master.tpl is used, its code page is run automatically, and this would have the advantage, of only ever being defined and ran in one spot.